# What is a good resource to learn about Monte Carlo simulations through examples?

Tags: references, simulation, monte-carlo

I am interested in learning more about Monte Carlo simulations and in particular refining my ability to take a *simulation approach* to complex examples.

An exemplar would be Peter Norvig's Python notebook on an [economics simulation](https://github.com/norvig/pytudes/blob/master/ipynb/Economics.ipynb) that was making the rounds recently.

Any resource (textbook/online) with many more such examples would be ideal.

Comment: Why not use our site?  It offers [hundreds of such examples](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=rand*+simulat*+is%3Aanswer+score%3A4) along with a search engine, semantic tags, commentary, competing solutions, and examples in multiple languages.

Comment: @whuber I feel a textbook would be more self-contained and efficient to read through. But I think using CrossValidated to supplement textbook learning is great suggestion and I will do so.