# Does the accepted sample based on the acceptance-rejection algorithm has the same distribution as X~$f(x)$?

Tags: bayesian, rejection-sampling, accept-reject

In Bayes Statistics, does the accepted sample based on the acceptance-rejection algorithm has the same distribution as X~$f(x)$?

Intuitionally it does, but how to prove it under the discrete and continuous cases respectively?

Comment: See section 3.1 of https://wwwusers.ts.infn.it/~milotti/Didattica/Bayes/Smith&Gelfand_1992.pdf for a proof that samples from the usual rejection sampler have the correct distribution

Answer (score 1):

First, acceptance-rejection is absolutely nothing specific to Bayesian statistics since it applies to any simulation experiment.

Second, the question as stated is unclear since $X\sim f(x)$ does not spell out how $f$ is related with the acceptance-rejection algorithm. If $f$ is the target distribution density and $g$ the instrumental distribution density then indeed the accept-rejection is valid. As established in every [simulation textbook](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/332570/7224).